# Laravel $model->increment() affects all rows, not just one

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

Trying to track page views using increment() except it affects every row instead of just the one

```
public function getPost($id) {
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->increment('views');

    return view('posts')->with(['post' => $post]);
}
```

I also tried this but it increments every row still

```
$counter = Post::where('id', $id)->increment('views');
```

The next thing I tried was manually incrementing it. Also affected all rows

```
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $viewCount = $post->views;
    $viewCount += 1;
    $post->views = $viewCount;
    $post->save();
```

Could it be possible the way I'm creating links on the page makes it increment all? Or could it be something else?

```
<a href="{{ route('getPost',['id'=>$post->id]) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
```

Comment: What is the use of ``getPost()`` exactly? Maybe it is called for every row. Are you using it to get your posts somewhere?

Comment: can you show the routes.php and posts.blade.php code, it will help analyze the code better.

Comment: NR: instead of ``$viewCount = $post->views; $viewCount += 1;`` you can do:   ``++$post->views;``

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where `getPost` is being called. It might be that you are calling it when rendering. It should move to `show` post in the controller and increment only when it is viewed.